# windows phone 8 Map API GeocodeQuery.SearchTerm not english got nothing

Tags: windows-phone-8, geocoding, here-api, windows-phone-8-sdk

I use [GeocodeQuery](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.maps.services.geocodequery%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) to look up the coordinates of a search term.

```
// Get your current position
var myPosition = await new Geolocator().GetGeopositionAsync(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1), TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));

// Define search
var geoQuery = new GeocodeQuery();
geoQuery.SearchTerm = "Taipei";
geoQuery.GeoCoordinate = new GeoCoordinate(myPosition.Coordinate.Latitude, myPosition.Coordinate.Longitude);
geoQuery.QueryCompleted += (s, e) => {
  if (e.Error == null && e.Result.Count > 0) {
    // e.Result will contain a list of coordinates of matched places.
    // You can show them on a map control , e.g.
    myMap.Center = e.Result[0].GeoCoordinate;
    myMap.ZoomLevel = 2;
  }
}
geoQuery.QueryAsync();
```

It works well! I got some location about "Taipei" successfully,

But, when I search "Taipei" in tranditional chinese "台北",

I got nothing in callback function geoQuery.QueryCompleted,

```
e.Result.Count = 0
```

How should I handle the GeocodeQuery search in different language?? 
Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The geocodequery use the system language to perform search. If you change your phone language to Chinese you should get results.